# Is it possible to log an event to cypress from within the non-spec code?

Tags: javascript, cypress

Say I have a simple code file:

*util.js*

```js
function add(x, y){
 return x + y;
}
```

*util.spec.js*

```js
describe("utils", ()=>{
  it("should add 2 and 4 together", ()=>{
    sum = add(2,4);
    expect(sum).to('eq', 6);
  })
});
```

Is it possible to add some command directly inside the `add()` function that will log an event to the cypress output? The test run on a remote server and a verbose log is required.

Something like this:
*util.js*

```js
function add(x, y){
 // cy.log('add function was just called with:', {x, y})
 return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress commands are just javascript, so yes ... what happened when you tried it?

Keep in mind you can't *return* the command value from the function and the timing might not be what you expect, but as "side effects" it should be ok.

**Timing/sequence**

```js
function add(x, y){
 cy.log('add function was just called with:', {x, y})   // logs 2nd
 return x + y;
}

describe("utils", ()=>{
  it("should add 2 and 4 together", ()=>{
    sum = add(2,4);
    console.log(sum)                                    // logs first
    cy.wrap(sum).should('eq', 6)
  })
});
```